# Error in SELECT command after changing date

Tags: string, sql-server-2008, selectcommand

Sir, I am using following script (complete aspx page) for dispaling 3 pivot tables from SQL sever 2008 database for December month 2012

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" %>

  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

 <script runat="server">

 </script>

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
    .style1
    {
        color: #800000;
        font-size: medium;
        font-family: "Comic Sans MS";
    }
    .style2
    {
        text-align: center;
        color: #0000CC;
        font-family: "Comic Sans MS";
        font-size: small;
    }
    .style3
    {
        font-size: large;
    }
    .style4
    {
        text-align: center;
        color: #800000;
        font-family: "Comic Sans MS";
        font-size: small;
    }
    .style5
    {
        font-size: small;
    }
</style>

<script runat="server" visible="True">
int TotalTTL1;
int GetTTL1(int Train)
{
    TotalTTL1 += Train;
    return Train;
}
int GetTotalTTL1()
{
    return TotalTTL1;
}

</script>

</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div style="text-align: center">



<p class="style4">
    <strong>Three Phase Locomotive</strong></p>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderColor="#CC0000" BorderStyle="Solid" 
    BorderWidth="2px" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" HorizontalAlign="Center" 
    ShowFooter="True" style="margin-top: 0px">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Equipment" SortExpression="Equipt" 
            FooterText="Grand Total">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Equipt") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Equipt") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate> 
            <FooterStyle Font-Bold="True" />
           <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BSL" HeaderText="BSL" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="BSL" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="AQ" HeaderText="AQ" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="AQ" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="KYN" HeaderText="KYN" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="KYN" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ASN" HeaderText="ASN" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="ASN" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="HWH" HeaderText="HWH" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="HWH" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="MGS" HeaderText="MGS" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="MGS" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="GMO" HeaderText="GMO" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="GMO" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="WAT" HeaderText="WAT" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="WAT" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ANGL" HeaderText="ANGL" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="ANGL" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="GZB" HeaderText="GZB" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="GZB" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LDH" HeaderText="LDH" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="LDH" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="JHS" HeaderText="JHS" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="JHS" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CNB" HeaderText="CNB" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="CNB" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="AJJ" HeaderText="AJJ" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="AJJ" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ED" HeaderText="ED" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="ED" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RPM" HeaderText="RPM" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="RPM" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BZA" HeaderText="BZA" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="BZA" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LGD" HeaderText="LGD" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="LGD" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="KZJ" HeaderText="KZJ" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="KZJ" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TATA" HeaderText="TATA" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="TATA" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BNDM" HeaderText="BNDM" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="BNDM" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BKSC" HeaderText="BKSC" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="BKSC" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="SRC" HeaderText="SRC" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="SRC" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BIA" HeaderText="BIA" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="BIA" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BRC" HeaderText="BRC" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="BRC" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BL" HeaderText="BL" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="BL" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TKD" HeaderText="TKD" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="TKD" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ET" HeaderText="ET" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="ET" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="NKJ" HeaderText="NKJ" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="NKJ" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total" SortExpression="TTL">
             <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# GetTTL1(int.Parse(Eval("TTL").ToString())).ToString()%>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <%# GetTotalTTL1().ToString()%>
                </FooterTemplate>
             <FooterStyle Font-Bold="True" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="Black" 
        HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
    <HeaderStyle Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="Black" 
        HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
    <RowStyle Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="Small" HorizontalAlign="Center" 
        VerticalAlign="Middle" />
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:EquipfailuresERConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT  Equipt, NULLIF([BSL],0) AS BSL, NULLIF([AQ],0) AS AQ, NULLIF([KYN],0) AS KYN,  NULLIF([ASN],0) AS ASN, NULLIF([HWH],0) AS HWH, NULLIF([MGS],0) AS MGS, NULLIF([GMO],0) AS GMO, NULLIF([WAT],0) AS WAT, NULLIF([ANGL],0) AS ANGL, NULLIF([GZB],0) AS GZB, NULLIF([LDH],0) AS LDH, NULLIF([JHS],0) AS JHS, NULLIF([CNB],0) AS CNB, NULLIF([AJJ],0) AS AJJ, NULLIF([ED],0) AS ED, NULLIF([RPM],0) AS RPM, NULLIF([BZA],0) AS BZA, NULLIF([LGD],0) AS LGD, NULLIF([KZJ],0) AS KZJ, NULLIF([TATA],0) AS TATA, NULLIF([BNDM],0) AS BNDM, NULLIF([BKSC],0) AS BKSC, NULLIF([SRC],0) AS SRC, NULLIF([BIA],0) AS BIA, NULLIF([BRC],0) AS BRC, NULLIF([BL],0) AS BL, NULLIF([TKD],0) AS TKD, NULLIF([ET],0) AS ET, NULLIF([NKJ],0) AS NKJ, NULLIF(([BSL] + [AQ] + [KYN] + [ASN] + [HWH] + [MGS] + [GMO] + [WAT] + [ANGL] + [GZB] + [LDH] + [JHS] + [CNB] + [AJJ] + [ED] + [RPM] + [BZA] + [LGD] + [KZJ] + [TATA] + [BNDM] + [BKSC] + [SRC] + [BIA] + [BRC] + [BL] + [TKD] + [ET] + [NKJ] ),0) AS TTL 
 FROM 
( 
SELECT Equipt, Shed 
FROM ERfailures WHERE Date &gt;= '12/01/2012' AND Date &lt;= '12/31/2012' AND loco_type = '3-Phase' AND classification = 'Loco'  
) x
PIVOT 
( 
COUNT(Shed) 
FOR Shed IN ([BSL],  [AQ],  [KYN],  [ASN],  [HWH],  [MGS],  [GMO],  [WAT],  [ANGL],  [GZB],  [LDH],  [JHS],  [CNB],  [AJJ],  [ED],  [RPM],  [BZA],  [LGD],  [KZJ],  [TATA],  [BNDM],  [BKSC],  [SRC],  [BIA],  [BRC],  [BL],  [TKD],  [ET],  [NKJ] ))  p">
</asp:SqlDataSource>




</form>
<p class="style5" style="text-align: center">
    <a href="mainpage.aspx">Back</a></p>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Now I want to change the line for January 2013 as

```
   FROM ERfailures WHERE Date &gt;= '01/01/2013' AND Date &lt;= '01/31/2013' AND loco_type = '3-Phase' AND classification = 'Loco'
```

It gives an error as

```
  Input string was not in a correct format."
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
 Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
 Stack Trace: 


[FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) +9591147
System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) +119
ASP.erequipfailurejanuary_aspx.__DataBind__control43(Object sender, EventArgs e) +106
System.Web.UI.Control.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e) +91
System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding) +92
System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind() +15
System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren() +201
System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding) +101
System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind() +15
System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren() +201
System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding) +101
System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind() +15
System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateRow(Int32 rowIndex, Int32 dataSourceIndex, DataControlRowType rowType, DataControlRowState rowState, Boolean dataBind, Object dataItem, DataControlField[] fields, TableRowCollection rows, PagedDataSource pagedDataSource) +166
System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable dataSource, Boolean dataBinding) +3896
System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data) +66
System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data) +14
System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback(IEnumerable data) +128
System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +33
System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +143
System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +74
System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind() +4
System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +66
System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.CreateChildControls() +75
System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +102
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +42
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2496"
```

What to do for resolve this issue? Please help.

Comment: It's not the SQL command itself that's giving the error - the GridView is failing when binding - one of the values is not in the correct format (for an Int32, it appears).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not your query. It is one of the values you are returning. Looks like you have a column in your binding destination that is expecting a number but is getting a non-numeric value.

Based on:

> [FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
>   System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options,
>   NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
>   +9591147 System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) +119
>   ASP.erequipfailurejanuary_aspx._*DataBind*_control43(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e)

Comment: Thanks for reply. Above code is working with date e.g. "FROM ERfailures WHERE Date >= '12/01/2012' AND Date <= '12/31/2012' AND loco_type = '3-Phase' AND classification = 'Loco'" But when only dates changed to 01/01/2013 nd 12/31/2013 it is failed to display. Why?

Comment: One more thing, new dates (January 2013) working, if footer sum script removed (Total or TTL field) from Gridview.

Comment: Because the dates that work do not include the bad rows in the resultset. I would suggest matching the column type in your binding destination to the data types in the resultset you are querying. If the column is not an int in the database, then you cannot be certain that the value of any row will be an int.

Comment: You are right. Error was due to some weired character in sql table data imported from excel worksheet.